# Is in mongodb something like prepared statements in php for security?

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, security

I am just learning mongodb and have one important question. Is in mongodb something for security like its in php? In php I could use something like:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE news SET shown = shown+1 WHERE newsID = :newsID");
$stmt->bindValue(":newsID", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

But what in mongodb? Its weird to see inserting variables directly into mongodb insert statement like:

```
db.products.insertOne( { _id: 10, "item": itemName, "qty": itemQuantity } );
```

Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: You don't need anything like prepared statements since MongoDB's query language is JSON, and not just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you would construct something like

```
db.products.insertOne( JSON.parse('{ _id: 10, "item": itemName, "qty": itemQuantity }') )
```

an SQL injections would be rather difficult. I guess no one does such code  voluntarily.

When you run have statement like `db.find({"someProperty": userInput})`
and a hacker tries to pass `{"$exists": true}` then it will result into `db.find({"someProperty": "{\"$exists\": true}"})` which should not return any result.

But as mentioned, using `JSON.parse()` or similar could be a security flaw.